# Magento 2: DHL Shipping Method Issue

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, dhl

From Admin I have added correct credentials for DHL, like Access ID, Password & Account Number. When i Enable then on Frontend,  it always display

[image]

I have set Allowed All Countries & My Shipping Address Country is also Valid.

Product has also Weight.

What is missing i'm in Setting or what's Wrong?

Comment: Did you tried this credentials in another Magento 2 project ? If not please try and check. If its gives same error then there must be error on credentials . If its working on another project then there must be something in your current project.

Comment: I have checked on 3 Magento 2 Projects + Credentials are correct

Comment: Do you have any custom module in your current project ? And did you find any error in log directory ?

Comment: For Shipping Yes we have Purchased Plugin & Installed. Nope this is error. How to check Request and Response for `https://xmlpi-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet`?